# PyQt: Let the user edit layout of the widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qgridlayout

I have a window containing two adjacent QTableWidgets and one full width QTextBrowser beneath them. They are all positioned inside a QGridLayout which spans to the whole window area. Now the problem is that I'd want to let the user deside what size each table has inside the window by allowing him/her to grab the the corner/border of the table to resize the table/grid cells. Is there some ready made ways in PyQt to achieve this? I could not find any, but maybe I just searched with the wrong keywords.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with [QSplitter](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplitter.html).